# How to only cin one input per line (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, cin

I'm new to C++ and working on a simple guessing game where you get 5 tries to guess a number between 1 and 100.
I'm having issues dealing with user inputs.

I've made it so that the program only accepts numbers between 1 and 100, and it ignores characters without crashing. The problem is that when I type in gibberish like 34fa1e8, the loop will run three times, using 34 the first time, 1 the second time, and 8 the last time, instead of ignoring the input like I want it to.

The code im using is here:

```
int check_guess() {
    int guess;
    do {
        cin >> guess;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }
    } while (guess < 1 || guess > 100);
    return guess;
}
```

How can I make the program dismiss inputs like these instead of accepting them separately?

Comment: Related: [How to test whether stringstream operator>> has parsed a bad type and skip it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504582/test-whether-stringstream-operator-has-parsed-a-bad-type?noredirect=1#comment37965807_24504582)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828937/how-to-make-cin-to-take-only-numbers

Comment: If I execute your code in a main function I get 34 and only one loop iteration: cout << check_guess() << endl // it prints 34 and exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and [stol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stol/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifstream::getline` to store the input in a `char` array. Then convert it to an integer using a function like this:

```
int convertToInteger(char const *s){
    if ( s == NULL || *s == '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
    int result = 0, digit = 1000;
    while((*s) && (digit > 0)){
        if ( *s >= '0' && *s <= '9' ){
            result +=  digit * (*s - '0');             
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
        ++s;
        digit /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The reason it works is because it will return 0 in case of failure and that's something your loop's condition will not accept. You also don't have to worry about negative numbers since your loop won't accept them anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I've given an answer like this before; an explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583733/error-when-user-input-numbers-characters).

You can even extended the solution to check for the specified range:

```c++
template <int min, int max>
class num_get_range : public std::num_get<char>
{
public:
    iter_type do_get( iter_type it, iter_type end, std::ios_base& str,
                      std::ios_base::iostate& err, long& v) const
    {
        auto& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(str.getloc());
        it = std::num_get<char>::do_get(it, end, str, err, v);

        if (it != end && !(err & std::ios_base::failbit)
                      && ctype.is(ctype.alpha, *it))
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
        else if (!(min <= v && v <= max))
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;

        return it;
    }
};
```

Now you can imbue the stream with the new locale and you need to restructure your loop to discard valid input. For example:

```c++
std::locale original_locale(std::cin.getloc());
std::cin.imbue(std::locale(original_locale, new num_get_range<1, 100>));

int check_guess()
{
    int guess;
    while (!(std::cin >> guess))
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.igore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```